# Using MailKit, can I get the subject or sender email without downloading entire message in POP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mailkit

I have an email with yahoo business and MailKit works with POP.  I want to download the message after finding a specific subject.  Or could I use IMAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the POP3 server supports the `TOP` extension, you can download just the message headers to first check the subject. To do that, you could do something like this:

```
if (client.Capabilities.HasFlag (Pop3Capabilities.Top)) {
    var headers = client.GetMessageHeaders (index);
    if (headers[HeaderId.Subject] == subject)
        message = client.GetMessage (index);
}
```

If your Yahoo account also supports IMAP, I would recommend using IMAP since IMAP allows you to query the server for messages with a given subject which is much more efficient than downloading the headers for every message to check if the subject matches the one you are looking for.

Comment: how can i get auto-submitted message header. i cannot see any id for it like headerid.autosubmitted

Comment: You can use `headers["X-Auto-Submitted"]` or whatever the name of the header is as a string (case gets ignored).

Comment: thanks.it worked with message.Headers["auto-submitted"]